# In SQL, I want to group the records but in order

Tags: sql-server

I have table with data as shown below. I have added the Insert query for proper visualization of data

[image]

Now I want to group them in order in below format such that if the data is not incremental and some `Issueno` are missing I need the count and range

```
Tickets                | Count | Status
-----------------------+-------+-----------------------------------    
100001809              |   1   | Void,Reissued,Transferred
100001810              |   1   | Valid Transferred
100001811-100001812    |   2   | Void,Reissued,Transferred
100001813-100001815    |   3   | Valid,Transferred
100001816-100002399    | 584   | Not issued
100002400-100002404    |   5   | Valid,Transferred
100002405-100002999    | 595   | Not issued
100003000              |   1   | Valid,Transferred
100003001              |   1   | Void,Reissued,Transferred
100003002-100003003    |   2   | Valid,Transferred
```

`Voidstatus='VO'` means it is void and if it null it means it is valid, `Reissued='Y'` means it is reissued and `TransacationName='EXPORT'` means transferred.

Grouping should be in such away that that each row compare data (first 3 column) from its next row,If it match it form 1 group else it form another group

`Issueno = 100001809` which is different with the below row so this form 1 grouping

Next row has `Issueno = 100001810` which is different from below row so that form another grouping with count as 1

`Issueno = 100001811` is same with next row having `issueno = 100001812` so this form 1 group with count as 2

Please find Insert query below

```
Create table Issue
(
    VoidStatus nvarchar(100),
    Reissued varchar(10),
    TransactionName varchar(100),  
    Issueno varchar(100)
)    

INSERT INTO Issue
    SELECT 'VO','Y' ,'EXPORT','100001809'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100001810'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'VO','Y','EXPORT','100001811'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'VO','Y','EXPORT','100001812'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, 'EXPORT', '100001813'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, 'EXPORT', '100001814'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, 'EXPORT', '100001815'  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, 'EXPORT', '100002400'
    UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100002401'

    UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100002402'

   UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100002403'

    UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100002404'

    UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100003000'

    UNION ALL

 SELECT 'VO','Y','EXPORT','100003001'

   UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100003002'

    UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL,NULL,'EXPORT','100003003'
```

Comment: You should clarify your question. Also scond image shows a column with many entries intended, you should use either one column per each, or one row per each for the status kinds of yours. I have made some markdown edits but main body is yours and is not very clear.

Comment: Please don't post links to screenshots or data; put the data in your question. Links expire and can't be found by the SO search.

Comment: Hi ,I have updated the Question,let me know if its unclear

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: according to the screenshot i am nearly sure it is sql-server-management-studio. while this really means nothing, it normally states the use of sqlserver...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is too much going on here to do it with a single insert into command.  You will need a stored procedure to run through the records and create the output table.  I don't know what database you are using but here is a solution for Access.  If you aren't using Access maybe you can change the syntax a bit to make it fit whatever stored procedure language you are using.

```
Sub CreateTickets()

    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim FirstIssueNo As Long
    Dim IssueNo As Long
    Dim VoidStatus As String
    Dim Reissued As String
    Dim TransactionName As String
    Dim Value As String

    Count = 1
    IssueNo = 0
    FirstIssueNo = 0

    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Issue ORDER BY IssueNo")
    If RS.BOF = False Then
        While RS.EOF = False
            If IssueNo <> 0 And ( _
                CLng(RS("Issueno")) <> IssueNo + 1 Or "" & RS("VoidStatus") <> VoidStatus Or "" & RS("ReIssued") <> Reissued Or "" & RS("TransactionName") <> TransactionName) Then

                Value = IIf(VoidStatus <> "", "Void,", "") & IIf(Reissued <> "", "Reissued,", "") & IIf(TransactionName <> "", IIf(VoidStatus = "", "Valid,", "") & "Transferred", "")
                If FirstIssueNo <> 0 And FirstIssueNo <> IssueNo Then
                    Ticket = FirstIssueNo & "-" & IssueNo
                    Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & Value
                    CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
                Else
                    Ticket = IssueNo
                    Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & IIf(VoidStatus <> "", "Void,", "") & IIf(Reissued <> "", "Reissued,", "") & IIf(TransactionName <> "", IIf(VoidStatus = "", "Valid,", "") & "Transferred", "")
                    CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
                End If
                If CLng(RS("IssueNo")) <> IssueNo + 1 Then
                    Value = "Not Issued"
                    Count = (CLng(RS("IssueNo")) - IssueNo - 1)
                    If (IssueNo + 1) <> (CLng(RS("IssueNo")) - 1) Then
                        Ticket = (IssueNo + 1) & "-" & (CLng(RS("IssueNo")) - 1)
                        Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & Value
                        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
                    Else
                        Ticket = (IssueNo + 1)
                        Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & Value
                        CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
                    End If
                End If
                FirstIssueNo = CLng(RS("IssueNo"))
                Count = 1
            Else
                Count = Count + 1
            End If

            IssueNo = CLng(RS("Issueno"))
            VoidStatus = "" & RS("VoidStatus")
            Reissued = "" & RS("ReIssued")
            TransactionName = "" & RS("TransactionName")

            RS.MoveNext
        Wend

        Value = IIf(VoidStatus <> "", "Void,", "") & IIf(Reissued <> "", "Reissued,", "") & IIf(TransactionName <> "", IIf(VoidStatus = "", "Valid,", "") & "Transferred", "")
        If FirstIssueNo <> 0 And FirstIssueNo <> IssueNo Then
            Ticket = FirstIssueNo & "-" & IssueNo
            Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & Value
            CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
        Else
            Ticket = IssueNo
            Debug.Print Ticket & " | " & Count & " | " & IIf(VoidStatus <> "", "Void,", "") & IIf(Reissued <> "", "Reissued,", "") & IIf(TransactionName <> "", IIf(VoidStatus = "", "Valid,", "") & "Transferred", "")
            CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO Ticket (Tickets,[Count],Status) VALUES (""" & Ticket & """," & Count & ",""" & Value & """);")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks jerry for the help